# Google Apps Script Slides add shadow to a shape

Tags: google-apps-script, google-slides-api

I am trying to add a shadow to a shape in slides via the Google Apps Script Api for slides. 
I followed https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations.pages/other#Page.Shadow

This is my updateShapeRequest object

```
{
      "updateShapeProperties":{
        "objectId":pageElementId,
        "shapeProperties":{

          "shadow":{
            "alignment": "RECTANGLE_POSITION_UNSPECIFIED",
            "alpha":0.5,
            "blurRadius":{"unit":"EMU"},
            "color":{
              "rgbColor": {
                  "red":0,
                  "green":0,
                  "blue":0
               },
            },
              "propertyState":"RENDERED",
              "rotateWithShape": false,
              "transform": {
                "scaleX": 1.5,
                "scaleY": 1.5,
                "unit": "PT"
              }
          }
        },
        "fields":"shadow"
      }
    }
```

But it doesnt work. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The official document says as follows.

> shadow: The shadow properties of the shape. If unset, the shadow is inherited from a parent placeholder if it exists. If the shape has no parent, then the default shadow matches the defaults for new shapes created in the Slides editor. **This property is read-only.** [Ref](https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations.pages/shapes#shapeproperties)

From this, in the current stage, `shadow` of `ShapeProperties` is the read-only. By this, unfortunately, the shadow cannot be added using UpdateShapePropertiesRequest with the batchUpdate method of Slides API. And also, in this case, in the current stage, [Slides service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides) cannot also achieve this.

So, how about requesting this as the future request to [the issue tracker](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker)?

#### References:

- [UpdateShapePropertiesRequest](https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations/request#updateshapepropertiesrequest)
- [shapeProperties](https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations.pages/shapes#Page.ShapeProperties)

Comment: Hello Tanaike, I was checking this feature out again at https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations.pages/other#shadow now  root level is NOT read only but certain attributes inside shadow is read only. Is this working now? I tried adding it but didnt work. Do you happen to have any updates?

Comment: @Kaushal Cavale Unfortunately, it seems that it is not updated. And when I saw the last updated date, it's "Last updated 2020-04-06 UTC.". [Ref](https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations.pages/other#shadow) It seems that it is still not updated after I posted this answer. I deeply apologize for this.

Comment: Thanks @Tanaike. Lots of features are not implemented still like Clip/ Mask, adding shadow to a shape, adding Gradient colors to a shape etc. All these are possible in the client app. But not via api.